# transfer function

Tags: transfer-function

Please help me in solving the following problem:

> Find the pulse transfer function and weighting sequence of the system described by the following difference equation: $$y[k+2]+ y[k+1]+(0.89)y[k]=r[k] \ ,$$ where $y[k]$ is the input and $r[k]$ is the output.

Comment: This looks like a homework problem.
Use the z transform.

Comment: So, what have you tried already and where did you get stuck?